# PssCreateSnapshot - access denied odd situation

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, winapi, pinvoke

I've created some code for performing clones of processes using `PssCaptureSnapshot` and then perform a mini dump of the clone.

However, on some processes I'm getting access denied when running `PssCaptureSnapshot` (running as elevated). That's not a problem at all, in fact the processes that I cannot perform a clone of, can also not be cloned using ProcDump (tool from SysInternals).

However, what is odd is that if I open a PowerShell `PSSession` to the localhost and run my application from there... it has no problems creating the clone!

Now what immediately popped to my head was... privileges. So I checked the privileges inside the `PSSession` against those outside and... Bingo! PSSession has literally all privileges known to man whereas outside the PSSession I have just a handful of privileges.

No biggie, I thought... I'll just start assigning myself privileges, one at a time, calling `PssCaptureSnapshot` in between. When I stop getting access denied, I know which privilege I need!

The plan was foolproof. That is... until I ran out of privileges to assign and I was still getting access denied...

So now I'm really clutching at straws: why does it work inside a PSSession but not outside, when all of the privileges are (theoretically) the same? How do I troubleshoot this further?

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I will gladly post code if you think it will help. But bearing in mind I get an access denied, the fact that it works inside a PSSession but not outside *and* the fact that ProcDump can also not create clones for these processes... I don't think the code is relevant.

**EDIT**

Results from whoami /all

local session:

```
USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name          SID
================== ===========================================
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx S-1-5-21-1509752874-53682476-648048294-1107


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------
(listing only groups that appear in this session, but don't appear in the other)
NT AUTHORITY\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON       Well-known group S-1-5-14                                       Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                    Well-known group S-1-5-4                                        Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                       Well-known group S-1-2-0


PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                  Description                               State
=============================== ========================================= ========
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Disabled
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Disabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Disabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege           Load and unload device drivers            Disabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege        Profile system performance                Disabled
SeSystemtimePrivilege           Change the system time                    Disabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege Profile single process                    Disabled
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege Increase scheduling priority              Disabled
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege       Create a pagefile                         Disabled
SeBackupPrivilege               Back up files and directories             Disabled
SeRestorePrivilege              Restore files and directories             Disabled
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Disabled
SeDebugPrivilege                Debug programs                            Enabled
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege    Modify firmware environment values        Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege       Force shutdown from a remote system       Disabled
SeUndockPrivilege               Remove computer from docking station      Disabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege         Perform volume maintenance tasks          Disabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege          Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege         Create global objects                     Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege   Increase a process working set            Disabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege             Change the time zone                      Disabled
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege   Create symbolic links                     Disabled

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.

Kerberos support for Dynamic Access Control on this device has been disabled.
```

inside PSSession:

```
USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name          SID
================== ===========================================
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx S-1-5-21-1509752874-53682476-648048294-1107


GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------
(listing only groups that appear in this session, but don't appear in the other)
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK                        Well-known group S-1-5-2



PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                  Description                               State
=============================== ========================================= =======
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege        Adjust memory quotas for a process        Enabled
SeSecurityPrivilege             Manage auditing and security log          Enabled
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege        Take ownership of files or other objects  Enabled
SeLoadDriverPrivilege           Load and unload device drivers            Enabled
SeSystemProfilePrivilege        Profile system performance                Enabled
SeSystemtimePrivilege           Change the system time                    Enabled
SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege Profile single process                    Enabled
SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege Increase scheduling priority              Enabled
SeCreatePagefilePrivilege       Create a pagefile                         Enabled
SeBackupPrivilege               Back up files and directories             Enabled
SeRestorePrivilege              Restore files and directories             Enabled
SeShutdownPrivilege             Shut down the system                      Enabled
SeDebugPrivilege                Debug programs                            Enabled
SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege    Modify firmware environment values        Enabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege         Bypass traverse checking                  Enabled
SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege       Force shutdown from a remote system       Enabled
SeUndockPrivilege               Remove computer from docking station      Enabled
SeManageVolumePrivilege         Perform volume maintenance tasks          Enabled
SeImpersonatePrivilege          Impersonate a client after authentication Enabled
SeCreateGlobalPrivilege         Create global objects                     Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege   Increase a process working set            Enabled
SeTimeZonePrivilege             Change the time zone                      Enabled
SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege   Create symbolic links                     Enabled

USER CLAIMS INFORMATION
-----------------------

User claims unknown.

Kerberos support for Dynamic Access Control on this device has been disabled.
```

Comment: The first thing to check is whether you're really getting the privileges you think you are.  How are you doing that?  But it might not be the privileges that matter, the access rules for the processes in question might only allow access to the local system account.

Comment: @HarryJohnston About the privileges, the function that assigns them (can't remember the name right now) returns a bool to identify whether it was successful in assigning the privilege or not. It always returns true. Also whoami /priv shows that privileges were now enabled (though it only shows a subset of privileges). As for the question about access, the PSSession runs as the exact same user.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Also I forgot to put in my question, but while the call to `PssCaptureSnapshot` fails with access denied, I can perform a dump of the process without first making a clone of it. That works fine, even outside a PSSession. This (also) leads me to believe that access rights are not a problem.

Comment: If you're talking about AdjustTokenPrivileges, it returns TRUE regardless of whether or not the privilege was available to be enabled or not.  If a privilege isn't shown by `whoami /priv` then it isn't available and can't be enabled.  It you're talking about actually changing the privilege assignments in the local security database, note that you have to log off and back in for that to take effect.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the pssession is running in the same user context if it has a different set of privileges.  Please run `whoami /all` from both the pssession and the local session and compare.  If in doubt, edit the output into your question.

Comment: @HarryJohnston updated question with result from whoami /all as requested. I removed the groups that exist in both sessions, as stated in the question. As you can see, same SID = same user context.

Comment: ... and the same set of privileges. :-)  Although it is curious that they are enabled by default in the remote session.  Also, contrary to my expectations, neither session has any of the more powerful privileges.  Best guess at this point is that (for some reason) you have to be running in the same Remote Desktop session (aka Terminal Services session) as the target process.  You can check what session a process is running in with Task Manager, using the Select Columns option to add the "Session ID" column, or with Sysinternals Process Explorer.

Comment: The pssession is probably running in session 0, which is reserved for non-interactive processes such as system services.  My guess is that the all of target processes you're having trouble with are also in session 0.

Comment: @HarryJohnston nice suggestion with the session ID, but unfortunately it appears to have nothing to do with session ID: **all** w3wp processes run as session 0 and there's only 1 I can't clone (out of 6).

Comment: Oh, it isn't surprising that you can clone processes in other sessions; there's obviously *something* special about the particular processes in question, perhaps something to do with shared memory or memory allocated by device drivers.  My guess is that, whatever it is that is different about these processes, it makes it impossible to clone them from a different session - and that's why it works OK when using a pssession.

Comment: (The most obvious possibility is that perhaps you can't clone a process from a different session if it has an active file mapping that is in the session rather than the global namespace.  That's still just a wild guess, though.)

Comment: Right, but how do I go about finding out *exactly* what that difference is?

Comment: Trial and error?  But I don't see that it matters, since you already know how to resolve the problem, by taking the clone from the same session as the target process.

Comment: But that's the thing, it's not got to do with being on the same session. Here's two examples:
1. I can't clone taskhostex that belongs to another logged in user if using local session, I can if using PSSession
2. I can't clone servermanager.exe that belongs to another logged in user if using local session, I can if using PSSession.

Comment: Even easier, then, if being in session 0 works for everything.  I'm not criticizing the question, mind you; if somebody knows another way to resolve the problem, that's great.  I'm just suggesting that you don't hold your breath waiting for an answer, there might not be one.  (It isn't particularly unusual in Windows to need to perform certain operations from a service, nor is it all that difficult to do.)

Comment: Right, but that doesn't tell me *what* the difference is between the session 0 that works and the local session that doesn't. Even if there's no better way, it would still be nice to be able to put the finger on *exactly* what is causing this behaviour. Bearing in mind the error is access denied, it should (must?) be possible to fix it, but first need to be able to pinpoint exactly where the problem lies. You said trial and error, but trial and error what exactly?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the difference between the processes you could dump and the processes you couldn't.  I only see two methodical ways to try to determine what is special about session zero in this context.  You could try to figure out what is special about the processes that you can only dump from session zero, and hope that provides a clue.  Or you could use a kernel-mode debugger to see what criteria Windows is applying when it rejects the request.  Personally I wouldn't want to put that much work into it, but YMMV.

Comment: ... it seems likely to me that the criteria Windows is applying is literally "only allow this request if the caller is in session zero", but since most of my guesses so far haven't panned out, I'd take this with a big grain of salt. :-)

Comment: how i understand - the `OpenProcess` - return access denied ? need exactly show next: 1) *dwDesiredAccess* requested in call `OpenProcess` 2) dump the target process *DACL* and *Label* (!) need open process with `READ_CONTROL` only access to do this. 3) dump the 2 tokens with which you can and fail `OpenProcess` - only 3 you and done but **partially** - not show integrity level of calling code (low,medium, high ?) and groups dump very bad - need exactly and complete groups list with attributes

Comment: @RbMm how would I find that out? I tried ProcMon but that shows no `OpenProcess` calls...

Comment: @cogumel0 - sorry, i misunderstand. i first think that you fail open process for capture. so you open process ok (but with what access mask - this is very important) and what is *CaptureFlags* in call - can show this info now ?

Comment: @cogumel0 - here most important which `PSS_CAPTURE_FLAGS` you use in call . if i have this situation locally - can be easy trace `PssCaptureSnapshot` internal, for view which is internal call return to you `c0000022`

Comment: @RbMm I use the following flags: `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE`, `PSS_CAPTURE_HANDLES`, `PSS_CAPTURE_HANDLE_NAME_INFORMATION`, `PSS_CAPTURE_HANDLE_BASIC_INFORMATION`, `PSS_CAPTURE_HANDLE_TYPE_SPECIFIC_INFORMATION`, `PSS_CAPTURE_HANDLE_TRACE`, `PSS_CAPTURE_THREADS` and `PSS_CAPTURE_THREAD_CONTEXT`.

Comment: @cogumel0 - interesting case. i be easy under debugger build call graph of `PssCaptureSnapshot` if have this fail on own machine. i can advice you next - separate flags - call `PssCaptureSnapshot(hProcess, PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE, 0,&SnapshotHandle)` - with only one flag each time - for look, what is flag fail. say `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` doing process fork (yes, under windows !) by call `ZwCreateProcessEx` - may be this fail.. so again my advice if you are interesting research - first of all found with which flag was fail. use only *one* flag per call

Comment: That I can tell you already, it fails with `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE`. If I pass all flags listed above with the exception of `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` it works. If I pass *just* `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` it also fails. And yet this is the most important flag ...

Comment: @cogumel0 - this is good. `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE` internally do **fork** of your target process by call `ZwCreateProcessEx` - i almost sure that this call and return to you access denied. be good if you can set **bp** under some debugger on this function and confirm this.. with this flag is call graph is very [small](https://prnt.sc/fe8k45) and you can easy debug function internal step by step

Comment: also - are your target process, which you try dump - not belong to job ? *If the job limits do not allow a new process to break away from the
job, ZwCreateProcess fails with STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.*

Comment: and with which access you open target process - you not show. hope not `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` ? you need `PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS` access for `PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE`. privilege (sedebugprivilege) here unrelated

Comment: @RbMm I don't make any calls to `OpenProcess` in my code. It might be that internally this is called, but not something I have control over which flags are used. Remember this is C# code.

Comment: I'm not sure of how to check if the process I'm trying to clone belongs to a job, but *if* this was the case, surely it would *always* fail, right? Remember in my case it fails if running in the local session but works if I run it in a PSSession.

Comment: @cogumel0 - `I don't make any calls to OpenProcess in my code` - but `PssCaptureSnapshot` take the *ProcessHandle* as first parameter - how you obtaining it ? which access you have to this handle ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145607/discussion-between-cogumel0-and-rbmm).

Comment: `c# code` - this is absolute no matter - because need little debug windows code of `PssCaptureSnapshot` - set bp to `ZwCreateProcessEx` - i almost sure that this call return to you `0xc0000022` - .. how check job - [IsProcessInJob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684127(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after relative long research with cogumel0 we found exactly root of the problem.

first of all we found that [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx) can failed when and only when it called with [`PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457841(v=vs.85).aspx) flag - so for capture a snapshot of all cloneable pages in the process.

despite we have process handle with all required access to process (say `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`) - for some processes [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx) return error. why ?

i note that error was **only if process is running in the some job**. (*for determinate this we can use [`IsProcessInJob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684127(v=vs.85).aspx)*) and [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx) can return in this case 2 different errors:

- `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA` - i view this in win8.1 and win10 - it
  returned say for some `chrome.exe` processes (not all)
- `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - this error happens only when process which we
  want snap - **run in another session** (compare our process) and this
  is **only in win8.1** - no this error in win10, even if process in
  job and in another session.

for understand why this happens - need look how [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx) internal implement [`PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457841(v=vs.85).aspx) semantic. it do it by fork target process (yes, fork under windows). for this task used undocumented [`ZwCreateProcessEx`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a1f754b3fe2cb7a542cc44364c6a85850) api. when *SectionHandle == 0* (win32 `CreateProcess` always pass here section created on exe file (*if say full true now `CreateProcess` use another api, this was early*)) [`ZwCreateProcessEx`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a1f754b3fe2cb7a542cc44364c6a85850) clone (fork) process (*ParentProcess*) instead create new one based on  *SectionHandle* (which based on some exe file)

but if *ParentProcess* in job - the child (our forked) process also will be placed in this job. and here can be problems.

at first job can have limit for  process count in job. if say job have this limit - no more than 1 process in job - [`ZwCreateProcessEx`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a1f754b3fe2cb7a542cc44364c6a85850) and fail with error `STATUS_QUOTA_EXCEEDED` - and as result [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457828(v=vs.85).aspx) return to us `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA`. this is `chrome.exe` case - for security reasons some chrome processes run in job (with limit in 1 process) (this processes also have *Untrusted Mandatory Level* but this not related to issue)

but even if job have no limit for active process count (or we not exceed this limit) in win8.1 - in job belong to another session - call fail with `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`. why this ? this already internal implementation details and now (in windows 10) it changed - no more this error - we can fork process even if it in job and another session. some hint why this we can got in [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx) page:

> All processes within a job must run within the same session as the
>   job.

so here some windows restriction related to job object and cross session.

how reproduce/test this error on windows 8.1 if interesting ? for my look most easy way - take some windows service running in session 0 - this service must be not critical for system (easy can start/stop it) and have own exe. for my look "msdtc.exe" perfect victim here. so open it, try snapshot first, than place in in job and after this - again try snapshot. and view different:

```
NTSTATUS status;
BOOLEAN b;
if (0 <= (status = RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b)))
{
    // GetProcessIdByName custom function not shown here 
    if (ULONG dwProcessId = GetProcessIdByName(L"msdtc.exe"))
    {
        DbgPrint("found dwProcessId=%x\n", dwProcessId);

        if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION |
            PROCESS_SET_QUOTA|PROCESS_TERMINATE , FALSE, dwProcessId))
        {
            BOOL bInJob;

            if (IsProcessInJob(hProcess, 0, &bInJob))
            {
                if (!bInJob)
                {
                    HPSS SnapshotHandle;
                    ULONG err;
                    if (!(err = PssCaptureSnapshot(hProcess, PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE, 0,&SnapshotHandle)))
                    {
                        PssFreeSnapshot(NtCurrentProcess(), SnapshotHandle);
                    }

                    DbgPrint("PssCaptureSnapshot=%u\n", err);

                    if (HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObject(0, 0))
                    {
                        bInJob = AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, hProcess);
                        CloseHandle(hJob);

                        if (bInJob)
                        {
                            if (IsProcessInJob(hProcess, 0, &bInJob) && bInJob)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("process in job now!\n");

                                if (!(err = PssCaptureSnapshot(hProcess, PSS_CAPTURE_VA_CLONE, 0,&SnapshotHandle)))
                                {
                                    PssFreeSnapshot(NtCurrentProcess(), SnapshotHandle);
                                }

                                DbgPrint("PssCaptureSnapshot=%u\n", err);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DbgPrint("process not in job !?\n");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DbgPrint("AssignProcessToJobObject error=%u\n", GetLastError());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DbgPrint("CreateJobObject error=%u\n", GetLastError());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DbgPrint("process already in job\n");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DbgPrint("IsProcessInJob error=%u\n", GetLastError());
            }

            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            DbgPrint("OpenProcess error=%u\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
}
else
{
    DbgPrint("RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE)=%x\n", status);
}
```

in windows 8.1 i got next dbgprint:

```
found dwProcessId=950
PssCaptureSnapshot=0
process in job now!
PssCaptureSnapshot=5
```

but in windows 10 another picture:

```
found dwProcessId=4d0
PssCaptureSnapshot=0
process in job now!
PssCaptureSnapshot=0
```

are this is windows bug or feature - hard to say